# Using WP_Http to post data to Webservice without blocking caller script

Tags: http-api

I've been using **WP_Http** to post data to a (third-party) webservice.

Their webservice **is slow like hell so I can't wait for their webservice's answer**.

I have tried using the parameter **blocking = false** but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is my code, the microtime has been used to measure the webservice's delay. I thought that using blocking = false, the script would not wait for the webservice to answer, yet it does wait...

```
// Preparing send to Webservice
$microtimebefore = round(microtime(true) * 1000);

$request = new WP_Http();
$response = $request->post($post_url, array('body' => $body, 'timeout' => 15, 'blocking' => false));

// We're using WP_Http with blocking = false so we are NOT waiting for the webservice response, so we cannot control the webservice's answer.
$responsebody = "OK";

$microtimeafter = round(microtime(true) * 1000);
$microtimeexecution = $microtimeafter - $microtimebefore;
```

Does any of you have any idea why the parameter blocking = false seems to be ignored ?

Thanks,

Cheers,

Comment: try with `"timeout" => 0.01` like wordpress do with the cron spawning https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-includes/cron.php#L365

Comment: Thanks @mmm it seems like an acceptable workaround.

This part of the script still takes 1000 milliseconds (I'm not really sure why... seems like no matter the timeout, some time is still needed to decide it timed out ??) but it's still better than the 5+ seconds the third party webservice needs)

Answer (score 0):

PHP is synchronous language by design so it must wait for each line to be executed. If you call post request with 15s timeout you must wait untill webservice send response or 15s timeout limit.

As I see in the core `blocking` parameter will not spawn process but simply do not parse response saving you a little time.
https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-includes/class-requests.php#L630

You can make request with very small timeout as @mmm said or spawn process using `exec` function.

```
exec('curl --data "param1=value1&param2=value2" http://url.com > /dev/null 2>&1 &');
```

If you do not want to wait for response but you will need it eventually you can use promise design pattern. https://github.com/reactphp/promise